# Rename [combinatorial-games] to [combinatorial-game-theory]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-rename-request

The [combinatorial-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-games) tag should be renamed to [combinatorial-games-theory](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-games-theory), because that is what it is about and what it is used for. The tag wiki says this, emphasis added by me:

> **Use for questions relating to Combinatorial Game Theory**, terminology and concepts, particularly in regard to the mathematical properties of abstract board and card games, and game solving and solved games.

All questions in this tag follow suit in being about combinatorial game theory (optimal strategies, game solving, etc).

If we left this as “combinatorial games” it reads like it is a tag to apply to any question about a game that happens to be combinatorial in some sense. It is like having “card games” for a tag, except the name “combinatorial games” is obscure enough to protect it from being overused generically.

This came up [in a separate meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/can-we-please-have-a-new-tag-cgt-as-an-alias-for-combinatorial-games#comment4952_1771) and I agree enough I'm requesting it distinctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. Unclear to me whether it makes sense to have this tagged separately from other forms of game theory, but this can be done either way.